# MySQL treating eszett character as "ÃŸ" during LOAD DATA operation

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, load-data-infile

I am trying to import a [small data set](https://github.com/patrickmaynard/playing-with-berlin-subways/blob/master/output.csv) of Berlin street addresses using MySQL's LOAD DATA statement. The problem is that after the import runs, all of the beautiful ß characters in the German street names have become ÃŸ sets.

Here's the create-table statement I used for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `subway_distances` (
  `STN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HNR` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lat` decimal(36,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lon` decimal(36,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Distance` decimal(45,20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

... and here is my MySQL shell code:

```
charset utf8;
TRUNCATE TABLE subway_distances;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/output.csv'
    INTO TABLE berlin.subway_distances
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\';
SELECT * FROM subway_distances LIMIT 0,10;
```

I have looked at output.csv in vim, and the eszett character appears to be fine there.

**I am assuming that I simply need a different encoding declaration in MySQL, but I'm not sure where to start.**

I am also assuming that collation doesn't matter yet, since I'm not comparing values -- just purely trying to get a valid import.

Comment: `ÃŸ` is Mojibake for `ß`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this relatively quickly. It looks like I just need to specify the CHARACTER SET value in my LOAD DATA statement. So the new statement looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/output.csv'
    INTO TABLE berlin.subway_distances
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\';
```